# Orchard module loading event

Tags: orchardcms

I'm very new to Orchard CMS and I have started writing my first module. I've been looking for a way to detect when my module has been initialized from the root website but have had no luck!

A colleague suggested using WebActivator and the PreApplicationStartMethod attribute to configure a method to be called on start up but this did not work.

Has anybody managed to accomplish this, is there an interface provided by orchard like IModule that will allow me to hook into module initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mix up Autofac's and Orchard's modules.
To execute some code when Orchard's module starts you need to implement IOrchardShellEvents interface (Activated method). Also don't forget to register your implementation in Autofac:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Bootstrapper>().As<IOrchardShellEvents>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, `IOrchardShellEvents` is an implementation of `IEventHandler`, which in turn is an implementation of `IDependency`, so I don't think you even need to register your implementation as stated above. All you need to do is implement `IOrchardShellEvents`, and Orchard will take care of the registration for you.

Answer (score 5):

There are two event handlers that might interest you.  `IFeatureEventHandler` and `IOrchardShellEvents`.  The `IFeatureEventHandler` interface gives you hooks for modules enabling, disabling, installing, and uninstalling.  The `IOrchardShellEvents` interface provides hooks for the activation and termination of the Orchard Shell. Something in there should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Implement an Autofac.Module and override the Load(ContainerBuilder) method!

```
using Autofac;

public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
         // Module initialization here!
    }
}
```

Comment: while this is an entry point, it is not the correct one, see the other answers

Comment: If this was the best answer in 2011, it's not the correct answer now.  Use IOrchardShellEvents or IFeatureEventHandler.

Comment: More specifically, you probably want IOrchardShellEvents since you want to be notified each time Orchard is initialized not just when your module is first activated.